# Difference between Merkle–Damgård and sponge-function used in KECCAK

Tags: cryptography, message-digest, sha-3, keccak

Hello to the nice Stackoverflow community!

I have difficulties understanding the difference between the Merkle–Damgård construction and the sponge-function used in KECCAK.
The Merkle–Damgård Construction takes in the message-blocks iteratively, but as of what I've found in descriptions, doesn't a sponge function do the same? Illustrations of both look quite similar and I just don't find an explanation I really understand.
Can someone explain the difference somewhat easier?

Answer (score 0):

So I expanded my search for sources using youtube videos. If someone has the same question, I think it is very well explained in this Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUI5C9stAEM

The explanation starts at **minute 18**. Hope this helps someone.
Have a nice day!

Comment: Link only answers die when the link dies.  Please provide at least a summary.